# Perl module not found

Tags: perl, perl-module

When I try to import a Perl module into my script, it says the module is not found.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use lib 'mnt/hgfs/scripting/perl/perlib/Array';

use Shell;

#define all global variables here

use List::MoreUtils 'first_index';
use List::MoreUtils 'last_index';

use Getopt::Long;

use vars qw(%vectorList); 

use Array::Compare;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Can't locate Array/Compare.pm in @INC (@INC contains:           mnt/hgfs/scripting/perl/perlib/Array /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at wellbiasing.pl line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at wellbiasing.pl line 12.
```

Although I have installed the `Array` module in the `perlib` directory, it says the module is not found.  `Array` is a directory inside the `perlib` directory which I created to put all the modules in.  Inside the `Array` directory, there is `Compare.pm`.  Why do I get the error?

Answer (score 10):

Change:

```
use lib 'mnt/hgfs/scripting/perl/perlib/Array';
```

to:

```
use lib 'mnt/hgfs/scripting/perl/perlib';
```

The `Array` directory should not be part of the Perl module search path.

Comment: to futher clarify, by writing it the way the OP did, Perl is trying to find `mnt/hgfs/scripting/perl/perlib/Array/Array/Compare.pm`, by doing it toolic's way it looks correctly for `mnt/hgfs/scripting/perl/perlib/Array/Compare.pm`